# Help finding voltage between two points

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-measurement, electricity, electrical, homework

[image]

So, how should I proceed to find U_ab (or V_ab)?

I have found I = -0.5mA, U_1=-2.5V, U_2 = -0.5V, U_3 = 2.0V.

How would I even find U_a and U_b separately so I can apply U_ab = U_a - U_b?

Also, does the 10v source receive or deliver power?

Comment: Title says current but you are asking about voltage.

Comment: @winny Oops, my bad. studying EE in another language :).

Comment: You don't need to find them separately.  Voltage is always relative so you can define that b is the ground which means Ub = 0 and you only need to find Ua. (but still relative to b) Start at b and walk to a and add up all the voltages on the way.

Comment: @Oldfart Great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at point b and walk to point a, adding up the voltages across components as you go.

You have two paths, so if you're being thorough walk *both* paths and make sure you get the same answer -- if you don't, you made an error.